# add a class to parent items only in menu

Tags: jquery

i am working on a menu where i want to add a class to parent menu items only through jquery. the code i wrote for it is working fine but only if the menu item dont have any child elements(drop down menu). now what changes should i make to add a class to parent items only on hover.

here is the html

```
<nav id="main-menu" style="display: block;">
  <ul id="menu-nav_menu" class="nav sf-js-enabled">
    <li class="menu-item cat-item">
      <a href="http://localhost/carp/?page_id=45" class="sf-with-ul">
        <span class="main_text">About CARP</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
        <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item">
          <a href="http://localhost/carp/?page_id=40">Vision</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
     <a href="http://localhost/carp/?page_id=48" class="sf-with-ul">
       <span class="main_text">Our Work</span>
     </a>
     <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="http://localhost/carp/?page_id=50">How To</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
   <a href="http://localhost/carp/?page_id=79">
     <span class="main_text">Gallery</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="http://localhost/carp/?page_id=81">
      <span class="main_text">Contact Us</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

here is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //to change the background image of previous closest menu item background
    $("#main-menu ul#menu-nav_menu li a").hover(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var i = $("#main-menu ul li a span").index($(this).parent() );
    $('#main-menu li a span').eq(i-1).addClass('mybg');
    $("#main-menu ul li a").mouseout(function() {
        $('#main-menu li a span').eq(i-1).removeClass('mybg');
    });

});
```

Comment: Use jQuery parent(); might render some results.

Comment: can you kindly edit my code i tried it but no luck

Comment: can you place your code in jsFiddle?

Comment: Create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the stripped down parts of the code.

Comment: HERE IS THE JSFIDDLE  http://jsfiddle.net/pK8BY/1/

Comment: What kind of fiddle is this? +1 for Daedalus.

Comment: Your jsfiddle seems to be missing the css that makes it a menu.

Comment: i always tried my best to make a question simplest according to the policy but i failed each and every time sorry guys for your time waste

Comment: yes jgreen i cant put all the css for menu here caz itsvery huge and will put you all in problmes

Comment: which item would you want to hover over and which item would you want to add a class to?

Comment: the CSS in the fiddle has an error, the jQuery is missing a pair of "});" and the fiddle library isn't set to use jQuery. If you fix those the basic highlighting should be somewhat functional

Comment: when i hover on main menu item not sub menu for now it add a class to the closest main menu item in back direction. got my point??

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to highlight the main menu item when the hover event occurs on it or its children. Simplest way to do it is using CSS:

```
#menu-nav_menu > li:hover > a { background-color: #FF0000; }
```

[CSS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pK8BY/5/)

---

Since you want to do it using jQuery:

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('#menu-nav_menu > li').hover(function() {
        $(this).children('a').toggleClass('myBg');
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.myBg { background-color: #FF0000; }
```

[jQuery Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pK8BY/4/)

---

Your structure for the hover event is incorrect, please refer to the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) for the proper usage.

Here's the [CSS Selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) for your reference.

Comment: it worked i took difficult steps i should improve my jqery i am infact new to it thanks by the way. thanks to every one

Answer (score 0):

this might not give you what you need.. but improving your jquery.. you don't need `mouseout()` there..

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //to change the background image of previous closest menu item background
  $("#main-menu ul#menu-nav_menu li a").hover(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var i = $("#main-menu ul li a span").index($(this).parent() );
     $('#main-menu li a span').eq(i-1).addClass('mybg');
  },function(){
     var i = $("#main-menu ul li a span").index($(this).parent() );
     $('#main-menu li a span').eq(i-1).removeClass('mybg');
  });


});
```

Comment: thnx for ur kind response. sure i need to improve my jquery